# Witcher 3 Weapons - What exactly is "Frost damage"?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Some weapons have a "Frost damage" stat, but it seems to be pretty rare.

The level 13 Deithwen silver sword for example has "+19 Frost damage".

I would guess it counts as "Elemental damage", so the sword would probably just do an additional 19 points of damage, assuming the enemy has no special "Elemental damage" protection.

Is my assumption correct? Or is there some other benefit I am missing?

Comment: Yeah, you're mostly right, but it also increases if the target is WEAK to a specific element.

Comment: @RainMaker: I failed to find any specific information about enemy resistances or weaknesses regarding damage types. Its a pity that the game isn't more specific about these things. Without that knowledge, its sometimes impossible to decide which weapon is the better choice.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Some bestiary entries mention weaknesses to some signs (e.g. the [Ekimmara](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Ekimmara) to Igni). I always assumed that meant fire damage just did more damage overall, whether it was delivered by sign or by burning damage... but i can't find anything that definitively says at the moment.

Comment: @king14nyr: Yes, the game makes you aware of some weaknesses, but not the strengths. For example, I would imagine that "Wild Hunt" enemies are immune to frost damage, but it seems that we have to keep guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I have been able to find regarding frost damage is a couple of Reddit threads asking the same thing. The most conclusive [answer](https://m.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/3bfmw3/found_a_sword_with_9_frost_damage_how_does_it_work/cslp8xx) states that:

> Frost damage counts as additional "Elemental damage".

Comment: I accepted this answer, because its probably correct and its still the best we got after nearly 5 years :)